# Variables in Ruby method names created by attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, variables, attr-accessor

I have an object that is using attr_accessor.  I want to be able to call a method on that object with a variable with `#send`.  My problem is that the `=` method doesn't seem to work.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

class Test_class
  def test_method(x)
    f = Foo.new
    f.send(x)
    f.send(x) = "test" #this doesnt work 
    f.send("#{x} =") "test" #this also doesn't work
    # How can I set bar? 
  end
end

t = Test_class.new
t.test_method("bar")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `f.send "#{x}=", "test"`. In Ruby, method names may include punctuation, such as `=` or `!`. The methods created by `attr_accessor :bar` are simply named `bar` and `bar=`. In fact, `attr_accessor :bar` is just shorthand for:

```
def bar
  @bar
end

def bar=(value)
  @bar = value
end
```

When you're calling `foo.bar = "baz"`, you're actually calling the `#bar=` method with `foo` as the receiver and `"bar"` as the first parameter to the function - that is, `foo.bar=("baz")`. Ruby just provides syntactic sugar for methods ending in `=` so that you can write the more natural-looking form.